# How to send mail automatically if Date expires

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, email

In our application if some one purchase a tool for and if the license provided is for some few days (suppose for a week or an year).. How to send a mail automatically to the ID given by him before a day or a few days .. If any one having worked out means it will be very helpful to me...

Thanks & Regards,
Dorababu

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume this subscriber information is being kept in a database somewhere?  How about a small console app that's scheduled to run every day which polls the data and looks for subscribers that are soon to expire?  Than just have that app send out some email reminder to the customer.

If this isn't what you're talking about, please elaborate.  The question is a bit unclear.

Comment: Ya i need in this way only and also we use to see in some sites for free registration for few days and after that we will get a mail to us in that fashion i would like to do...

Comment: @Dorababu: It sounds like a polling application is what you're looking for.  Just a simple console application (I recommend that over a Windows Service so as to separate the application from the scheduling... easier to maintain over time) that hits the database, runs its comparison logic, and sends emails.

Comment: Is there any type of working application or any link can u please provide me

Comment: @Dorababu: If you're asking "how do I write an application" then I think we may be getting beyond the simple question/answer format of StackOverflow.  Are you just looking for the specific objects/namespaces you need for sending emails?  Google can help you tremendously there, but System.Net.Mail is the gist of it.  If you're looking for how to write an application in C#, I'd recommend finding a beginner's book on the subject.

Comment: I already did an application to send an Email after registration and all other